# Is there a way to embed a simple IDE into an html form?

Tags: jquery, html, ide

I am attempting to build some programming quizzes where we can save user responses and review them at a later date. I am quite familiar with how all the backend stuff should work, but I have no idea how to create a friendly environment for users to enter in code on the frontend.

Here's what I need:

- Syntax highlighting (at least HTML/CSS, PHP, and Javascript/JQuery
- A way to specify on a per-textarea basis which language the answer should be in
- Something that is compatible with JQuery if possible.

Does anyone know of a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CodeMirror editor which is very robust and supports various languages.

http://codemirror.net/

Take a look at the below link which gives comparison of widely used client side editors available along with their pros and cons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

Answer (score 0):

My company uses Edit Area, which I think suits your needs:

http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

Demo: http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html